# Chrome Extension add button to each image on a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to append a button to each image on a webpage using a Chrome Extension. I have the following code in my content script:

```
var imagesArray = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(imagesArray);

for (const img of imagesArray) {
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerHTML = "button";
    button.onclick = function() {
        console.log("clicked");
    }
    
    img.append(button);

}
```

I am able to get all the images and I know I can append buttons, I just don't know how to append the button onto the image. Any help is appreciated

Comment: tag img can not have child. The only way to do that is you create new element for the parent of the button or as the sibling element of the image.

Comment: what do you mean new element for parent of the button?

Comment: sorry, it is not new. but you can check the what is the parent element and append the button there.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help

Comment: is there any way you know how I can get the button to show only on hover of the image?

Comment: yes can do this `var button =  document.createElement("button");` and add id like this      `button.id = 'btnId';` and than come on css get button to id like this in css  `#btnId:hover { display: block }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this in the css. If you are able to add any css. Thanks

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

img:hover + button {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300" />
<button>My Button</button>
```

Comment: thanks! any way to be able to show the button on top of the image? right now it appears below so I can't click it

Comment: just try play around with any css position. you can create parent element relative, and the button is absolute. and also don't forget with z-index. good luck

Answer (score 2):

Use this line `document.body.appendChild(button); <-- use this line`  down this `img.append(button)`